# How can I find with scapy wireless networks around?

Tags: python, wifi, wireless, scapy

How can I find with scapy wireless networks around? If I do `sniff()` and `if pkt.haslayer(Dot11)` and then `if pkt.info` then I collect them but very slow, for example my Android phone do it in seconds and this script in minutes or even more...

Comment: Are you switching channels?

Comment: I sniff on `mon0` started by `airmon-ng`

Answer (score 6):

The reason for the difference is that your phone is actively looking for WiFi points by sending out requests to any access points nearby - sniff is listening for any passing traffic.

You might find is a lot quicker to:

1. Specifically select your network adapter - so you are not sniffing all adapters.
2. Do some digging to find out how to actively query for wifi networks and use `sr` with such packets, read the IEEE 802.11 specification to find out more, *I would especially look for "Probe request frame"*.

The example on how to send WiFi packets from [packet header](http://blog.packetheader.net/2014/01/sending-80211-packets-with-scapy.html) may well help, *(not my code and not tested by me)*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
802.11 Scapy Packet Example
Author: Joff Thyer, 2014
"""

# if we set logging to ERROR level, it supresses the warning message
# from Scapy about ipv6 routing
#   WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *


class Scapy80211():

    def  __init__(self,intf='wlan0',ssid='test',\
          source='00:00:de:ad:be:ef',\
          bssid='00:11:22:33:44:55',srcip='10.10.10.10'):

      self.rates = "\x03\x12\x96\x18\x24\x30\x48\x60"

      self.ssid    = ssid
      self.source  = source
      self.srcip   = srcip
      self.bssid   = bssid
      self.intf    = intf
      self.intfmon = intf + 'mon'

      # set Scapy conf.iface
      conf.iface = self.intfmon

      # create monitor interface using iw
      cmd = '/sbin/iw dev %s interface add %s type monitor >/dev/null 2>&1' \
        % (self.intf, self.intfmon)
      try:
        os.system(cmd)
      except:
        raise


    def Beacon(self,count=10,ssid='',dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'):
      if not ssid: ssid=self.ssid
      beacon = Dot11Beacon(cap=0x2104)
      essid  = Dot11Elt(ID='SSID',info=ssid)
      rates  = Dot11Elt(ID='Rates',info=self.rates)
      dsset  = Dot11Elt(ID='DSset',info='\x01')
      tim    = Dot11Elt(ID='TIM',info='\x00\x01\x00\x00')
      pkt = RadioTap()\
        /Dot11(type=0,subtype=8,addr1=dst,addr2=self.source,addr3=self.bssid)\
        /beacon/essid/rates/dsset/tim

      print '[*] 802.11 Beacon: SSID=[%s], count=%d' % (ssid,count)
      try:
        sendp(pkt,iface=self.intfmon,count=count,inter=0.1,verbose=0)
      except:
        raise


    def ProbeReq(self,count=10,ssid='',dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'):
      if not ssid: ssid=self.ssid
      param = Dot11ProbeReq()
      essid = Dot11Elt(ID='SSID',info=ssid)
      rates  = Dot11Elt(ID='Rates',info=self.rates)
      dsset = Dot11Elt(ID='DSset',info='\x01')
      pkt = RadioTap()\
        /Dot11(type=0,subtype=4,addr1=dst,addr2=self.source,addr3=self.bssid)\
        /param/essid/rates/dsset

      print '[*] 802.11 Probe Request: SSID=[%s], count=%d' % (ssid,count)
      try:
        sendp(pkt,count=count,inter=0.1,verbose=0)
      except:
        raise



    def ARP(self,targetip,count=1,toDS=False):
      if not targetip: return

      arp = LLC()/SNAP()/ARP(op='who-has',psrc=self.srcip,pdst=targetip,hwsrc=self.source)
      if toDS:
        pkt = RadioTap()\
                /Dot11(type=2,subtype=32,FCfield='to-DS',\
                addr1=self.bssid,addr2=self.source,addr3='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')\
                /arp
      else:
        pkt = RadioTap()\
                /Dot11(type=2,subtype=32,\
                addr1='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff',addr2=self.source,addr3=self.bssid)\
                /arp

      print '[*] ARP Req: who-has %s' % (targetip)
      try:
        sendp(pkt,inter=0.1,verbose=0,count=count)
      except:
        raise

      ans = sniff(lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(ARP) and x.op == 2,
        store=1,count=1,timeout=1)

      if len(ans) > 0:
        return ans[0][ARP].hwsrc
      else:
        return None


    def DNSQuery(self,query='www.google.com',qtype='A',ns=None,count=1,toDS=False):
      if ns == None: return
      dstmac = self.ARP(ns)

      dns = LLC()/SNAP()/IP(src=self.srcip,dst=ns)/\
        UDP(sport=random.randint(49152,65535),dport=53)/\
        DNS(qd=DNSQR(qname=query,qtype=qtype))

      if toDS:
        pkt = RadioTap()\
                /Dot11(type=2,subtype=32,FCfield='to-DS',\
                addr1=self.bssid,addr2=self.source,addr3=dstmac)/dns
      else:
        pkt = RadioTap()\
                /Dot11(type=2,subtype=32,\
                addr1=dstmac,addr2=self.source,addr3=self.bssid)/dns

      print '[*] DNS query %s (%s) -> %s?' % (query,qtype,ns)
      try:
        sendp(pkt,count=count,verbose=0)
      except:
        raise

# main routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print """
[*] 802.11 Scapy Packet Crafting Example
[*] Assumes 'wlan0' is your wireless NIC!
[*] Author: Joff Thyer, 2014
"""
    sdot11 = Scapy80211(intf='wlan0')
    sdot11.Beacon()
    sdot11.ProbeReq()
    sdot11.DNSQuery(ns='10.10.10.2')
```

Comment: I do this `sniff()` on `mon0` from `airmon-ng`.

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote a script that could scan wireless network . 
Its simple to use :

```
python rs.py mon0
```

Here mon0 is our interface. There are comments in the code to understand it properly.

```
#Implementation of a wireless scanner using Scapy library

#!/usr/bin/env python
# rs.py - Wireless AP scanner 
#author rahil sharma
# date 15/3/2013   @rs
#usage python rs.py mon0
#where mon0 is your monitoring interface
#used this using my alfa card in bactrack
import sys, os, signal 
from multiprocessing import Process

from scapy.all import *

interface='' # monitor interface
aps = {} # dictionary to store unique APs

# process unique sniffed Beacons and ProbeResponses. 
#haslayer packet has Dot11 layer present
#ord() string to integer ex ord('a) will give 97
def sniffAP(p):
    if ( (p.haslayer(Dot11Beacon))):
        ssid       = p[Dot11Elt].info
        bssid      = p[Dot11].addr3    
        channel    = int( ord(p[Dot11Elt:3].info))
        capability = p.sprintf("{Dot11Beacon:%Dot11Beacon.cap%}\
                {Dot11ProbeResp:%Dot11ProbeResp.cap%}")

        # Check for encrypted networks
    #now we put Dot11Beacon.cap info in capability and using regular expression search inbuilt function in python we search for privacy if it is present then the network is encrypted
    #output of the above cap file is somewhat like this short-slot+DSSS-OFDM+res15+ESS
        if re.search("privacy", capability): enc = 'Y'
        else: enc  = 'N'

        # Save discovered AP
        aps[p[Dot11].addr3] = enc

        # Display discovered AP    
        print "%02d  %s  %s %s" % (int(channel), enc, bssid, ssid) 

# Channel hopper - we are making a channel hopper because we want to scan the whole wireless spectrum.
#first choose a random channel using randrange function
#use system to run the shell command iw dev wlan0 set channel 1
#exit when a keyboard interrupt is given CTrl+c
def channel_hopper():
    while True:
        try:
            channel = random.randrange(1,15)
            os.system("iw dev %s set channel %d" % (interface, channel))
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
            # Capture interrupt signal and cleanup before exiting
#terminate is used to end the child process
#before exiting the program we will be displaying number of aps found etc.
#here Cntrl+c is used to 
#signal_handler used to do clean up before the program exits
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    p.terminate()
    p.join()

    print "\n-=-=-=-=-=  STATISTICS =-=-=-=-=-=-"
    print "Total APs found: %d" % len(aps)
    print "Encrypted APs  : %d" % len([ap for ap in aps if aps[ap] =='Y'])
    print "Unencrypted APs: %d" % len([ap for ap in aps if aps[ap] =='N'])

    sys.exit(0)
#use this for command line variables 
#for checking the number of command line variables and if they are in right order
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Usage %s monitor_interface" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(1)

    interface = sys.argv[1]
#take mon0 as interface given in the fist command line variable
    # Print the program header
    print "-=-=-=-=-=-= rs_scan.py =-=-=-=-=-=-"
    print "CH ENC BSSID             SSID"

    # Start the channel hopper
    #In multiprocessing, processes are spawned by creating a Process object and then calling its start() method
    p = Process(target = channel_hopper)
    p.start()

    # Capture CTRL-C 
    #this will call the signal handler CTRL+C comes under the SIGINT
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    # Start the sniffer
    sniff(iface=interface,prn=sniffAP)
    #inbuit scapy function to start sniffing calls a function which defines the criteria and we need to give the interface`enter code here`
```